# Apache POI Date Parsing One Second Off

Tags: apache-poi

I'm parsing an Excel spreadsheet with a date in it. The results from POI are off by 1 second compared to what's displayed in Excel.

The unformatted data in Excel is: 43261.5027743056
The cell in Excel has a format of: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
The field in Excel displays as: 6/10/2018  12:04:00 PM

The POI parser (v 4.0.1 and 4.1.0 both) parse it as:

- Value: 43261.502774305598
- Format: mm/dd/yyyy\ hh:mm:ss
- Result: 6/10/2018  12:03:59 PM

Here's my code:

```
private final DataFormatter formatter;

case NUMBER:
    String n = value.toString();
    if (this.formatString != null) {
      thisStr = formatter.formatRawCellContents(Double.parseDouble(n), this.formatIndex, this.formatString);
    } 
    else thisStr = n;
    break;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the binary floating point problem. This also exists but it should not impact seconds of time.

The problem is that your value `43261.5027743056` is not really exact the date time `06/10/2018 12:04:00` but `06/10/2018 12:03:59.700`. So it is `06/10/2018 12:03:59` plus `700` milliseconds. You could see this if you would formatting the cell using the format `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss.000` in `Excel`.

For such values there is a discrepancy between `Excel`'s date formatting and `apache poi`'s  `DataFormatter`, which uses `Java`'s date format. When `Excel` shows the date time value `06/10/2018 12:03:59,700` without milliseconds, then it rounds to seconds internally. So `06/10/2018 12:03:59.700` is shown as `06/10/2018 12:04:00`. `Java`'s date formatters don't round but simply don't show the milliseconds. So `06/10/2018 12:03:59.700` is shown as `06/10/2018 12:03:59`.

`Apache poi`'s [DateUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html) provides methods which rounds seconds. But those methods seems not be used in `DataFormatter`.

As workaround we could override `formatCellValue` of `DataFormatter` to do so.

Complete example:

Excel:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.util.LocaleUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ConditionalFormattingEvaluator;

import java.util.Date;

class ExcelParseCellValues {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Excel.xlsx"));

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter() {
   @Override
   public String formatCellValue(Cell cell, FormulaEvaluator evaluator, ConditionalFormattingEvaluator cfEvaluator) {
    CellType cellType = cell.getCellType();
    if (cellType == CellType.FORMULA) {
     if (evaluator == null) {
      return cell.getCellFormula();
     }
     cellType = evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
    }
    if (cellType == CellType.NUMERIC && DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell, cfEvaluator)) { //we have a date
     CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
     String dataFormatString = style.getDataFormatString();
     if (!dataFormatString.matches(".*(s\\.0{1,3}).*")) { //the format string does not show milliseconds
      boolean use1904Windowing = false;
      if ( cell != null && cell.getSheet().getWorkbook() instanceof Date1904Support)
       use1904Windowing = ((Date1904Support)cell.getSheet().getWorkbook()).isDate1904();
      boolean roundSeconds = true; //we round seconds
      Date date = DateUtil.getJavaDate(cell.getNumericCellValue(), use1904Windowing, LocaleUtil.getUserTimeZone(), roundSeconds);
      double value = DateUtil.getExcelDate(date);
      return super.formatRawCellContents(value, style.getDataFormat(), dataFormatString, use1904Windowing);
     }
    }
    return super.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator, cfEvaluator);
   }
  };

  CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = creationHelper.createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
    System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
   }
   System.out.println();
  }

  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

```
Description of value  Floatingpoint value  DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss.000    DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss   
Your example value    43261,5027743056     06/10/2018 12:03:59.700    06/10/2018 12:04:00   
Exact Datetime 12:04  43261,5027777778     06/10/2018 12:04:00.000    06/10/2018 12:04:00   
Exact minus 500 ms    43261,5027719907     06/10/2018 12:03:59.500    06/10/2018 12:04:00   
Exact plus 500 ms     43261,5027835648     06/10/2018 12:04:00.500    06/10/2018 12:04:01   
Exact minus 501 ms    43261,5027719792     06/10/2018 12:03:59.499    06/10/2018 12:03:59   
Exact plus 501 ms     43261,5027835764     06/10/2018 12:04:00.501    06/10/2018 12:04:01
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this when you parse the cell value as a double. Not all decimal values can be represented exactly as doubles. The nearest double to `43261.5027743056` is `43261.502774305597995407879352569580078125`, which rounds to the value you're seeing.

Comment: Is there a better way to parse the data than into a Double then?

Comment: How about https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell- ?

Comment: @MSquared It's not a matter of how you parse. The value you're seeing in Excel fundamentally cannot be represented as a double. Perhaps you should use a decimal instead.