# NPOI DateCell is 1 second off from time in Excel

Tags: excel, date, npoi

I have an excel document with times listed as "02:30" ... however, when iterating through them using NPOI, the DateCellValue flips to "02:29:59" ... This first happens on 1/1/2019 (which correctly stores as "02:30") but then on 1/2/2019 it flips to "02:29:59" ... Does anyone know how to have it simply get the value of the cell without trying to do any voodoo to it? It's obviously taking into account perhaps a leap second, or something? It is, however, clear as day in Excel as "02:30", and at my breakpoint with:

```
[Model].DepartureDttm = row.GetCell(j).DateCellValue [1/2/2019 2:29:59 AM]
```

Comment: I've also tried with 

    new DateTime(row.GetCell(j).DateCellValue.Ticks,DateTimeKind.Utc) same result.. 1 second off.

Comment: Some progress. I believe the user did the Excel drag trick to add 1 day to each row - it probably messes something up. I manually overwrote 1/2/2019 02:30 and it corrected... Question remains though, any way to simply take the value of the cell? Changing it to string is not an option - requirement that it must be a date cell with custom format "d-mmm-yyyy h:mm" ... Real users would probably not do the drag trick as departure times will change day to day, but it would be good to code for it just in case.

Comment: You should put those comments in your question, especially the second one that is the key to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the only one that have faced this problem. Here's a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875230/1351076).

You can use the `DateUtil.GetJavaDate` coming with `NPOI` to resolve this issue . You can create this basic extension method:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime DateCellValueRounded(this ICell cell)
    {
        return DateUtil.GetJavaDate(cell.NumericCellValue, false, TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone, true);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```cs
DateTime date = row.GetCell(index).DateCellValueRounded;
```

---

`GetJavaDate` signature (the last parameter set to `true` does the job):

```cs
public static DateTime GetJavaDate(double date, bool use1904windowing, TimeZone tz, bool roundSeconds);
```